# adding Environmental variable linux

Tags: linux, azure, environment-variables

I am trying to add environmental variable to my linux server in azure.
I googled and came up with a way of going as `root` then going to environmental file and editing it directly from there.
Want to know if this is the right way. Or do I have to add parenthesis like this.
ENVIRONMENT="testing".

Or is editing that file like that the right way. Since I want it to be there permanently.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's correct.
Keep in mind that this variable will be set globally after next reboot.

For this session you can set it by following command:

```
export ENVIRONMENT=testing
```

Comment: Thanks! I was actually worried about that, if its going to be only for the following session or globally.